# Is it possible to install and import modules in the same file? (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-import

I have some trouble running my Python script under Windows.
My code looks like this:

```
import os
try:
    from fabric.api import run
except ImportError:
    if os.name == 'posix':
        os.system('pip install fabric')
    elif os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('C:\Python27\python.exe D:\Fabric-1.10.1\setup.py install')
    from fabric.api import run
```

It works under Linux, but I got ImportError under Windows.
I can make it work by putting try-except clause in another script and activating the main script from there, like this:

```
import os
try:
    from fabric.api import run
except ImportError:
    os.system('C:\Python27\python.exe D:\Fabric-1.10.1\setup.py install')
os.system('C:\Python27\python.exe C:\some_path\main_script.py')
```

It works, but I would like to avoid creating separate script just for imports and installing modules.
Is there any way of reloading the environment under Windows, so that newly installed module will be visible to Python right away?

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you only plan to run your script on your own machine, there is no need to try to install the module every time you run the script; it's enough to do this once. If you plan to distribute the script, the hard-coded path will not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try:
    from fabric.api import run
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'fabric'])
    from fabric.api import run
```